# How to add excerpt in a page content WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

How to add excerpt in a page content?

I have a custom page template that call the child pages of a parent page and displayed it to a separate page using shortcode. But I want to limit the words that will be displayed every page (25 words) and put a "Read more" button.

How to do this?

```
<?php
    $ids = array();
    $pages = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
        if ($pages){
            foreach ($pages as $page){
                $ids[] = $page->ID;
            }
        }
    $paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
    $args = array(
            "paged" => $paged,
            "post__in" => $ids,
            "posts_per_page" => 3,
            "post_type" => "page"
    );
    query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
<div class="news-box">
    <div style="margin: 1em 0 0 0;"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
    <div class="news-date"><?php the_date(); ?></div>
    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif;
            paging_nav();
            wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20);?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
```

With this the word limit will be 20 and a read more link will be there. Instead

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

you can use it.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_the_except()` and pass the post id to get the excerpt of post in the loop.

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?>
<div class="news-box">
    <div style="margin: 1em 0 0 0;"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
    <div class="news-date"><?php the_date(); ?></div>
    <div>
      <?php echo get_the_excerpt( $postid ); ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $postid ); ?>" class="button">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add a filter the the excerpt in your `functions.php` file.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 25;
}
?>
```